# Disabling authentication for a single page (ColdFusion)

Tags: security, authentication, coldfusion, fw1

Let me start by saying I am not really a full-stack developer and this is out of my scope of understanding. I have tried searching for an answer but I can't find anything relevant. If you have any reasons to share they would be much appreciated!

I am working on a website running on coldfusion and [framework one](http://framework-one.github.io/documentation/). I've been instructed to make a single specific page accessible without authentication. I know this might seem like a bad idea, security wise I have no idea how dangerous this really is but it doesn't seem great. Regardless, those are my instructions.

Where would I even do something like this? Is there some sort of "authenticator" action that I can disable? When visiting a page on the domain while logged out the user is just redirected to the initial login page. Perhaps I can disable this redirect? I've looked in the relevant controller and view pages for the area of the site I'm working on but I can't find anything and it's hard for me to google without much knowledge on the topic to begin with. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If a page does not need to be secured behind some sort of authentication then it should not be under the secure area of the site. Having said that, FW /1 does not have any specific code to secure pages, It is merely a framework that wires things together for you as a developer. The redirecting is happening somewhere in your code base. You have not shared enough details here for us to help you. We would need to see the code.

Comment: hm thank you, that is helpful actually. There isn't really an unsecured area, just the login page but if I can find the redirect maybe I can put some condition in to stop it.

Comment: I don't know how familiar you are with ColdFusion but this type of thing is typically done in a file named `Application.cfc` as it is run on every request. Good luck.

Comment: I should have added... using FW/1 gives you other options for processing during a request. See [this section in the docs as another potential hook](https://github.com/framework-one/fw1/wiki/Developing-Applications-Manual#designing-controllers). Specifically the `before()` method discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Since you state that you don't have experience with ColdFusion this answer is kept simple and does not try to explain how ColdFusion applications work or what an `Application` scope is in ColdFusion.

1. create a `sub-folder` within your original application folder
2. create your non-secure page within this new `sub-folder`
3. create another page under the same `sub-folder` named `Application.cfm` with the following code (it's just a comment, it's an empty page but it will prevent the code that re-directs to login to execute)

***code for Application.cfm***

`<!--- // this folder is not secure --->`

---

If this does not work for you because you need access to stuff that is part of the secured application, let me know and I'll update my answer but will get a bit more complex like you'll need to find out where the redirection to login takes place and you'll need to understand what you're doing in ColdFusion.